# sudo apt-get install php5-xsl gives an 403 Forbidden error

Tags: php, ubuntu, xslt, apt-get

When installing the php5-xsl package, I get errors:

> Err http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php5-5.6/ubuntu/ trusty/main php5-> xsl amd64 5.6.14+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 403  Forbidden
>
> E: Failed to fetch [http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php55.6/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php5/php5-xsl_5.6.14+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1_amd64.deb](http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php55.6/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php5/php5-xsl_5.6.14+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org%7Etrusty+1_amd64.deb)  403  Forbidden
>
> E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?

I tried also this before installing:

> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get upgrade

But with no luck.
How can I install php5-xsl? I need this in my PHP project because this code gives a fatal error (class not found):

> new \XSLTProcessor();

Thank you!